# How do I primitive $\sin(x)\cos^3(x)$ step by step?

Tags: primitive-roots

I tried to primitive $\sin(x)\cos^3(x)$ step be step, but I got stuck.

Can I use substitution? $[\sin(x)]' =  \cos(x)$
And write $\cos^3$ as $\cos^2(x)*\cos(x)$
And also write the function $\sin(x)\cos^2(x)*\cos(x)dx$ as $\sin(x)\cos^2(x)d(\sin(x))$

Comment: Just let $u=\cos x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Could you please explain that a bit more?

Comment: If $u=\cos x$, then $du=-\sin x \,dx$; so then $\int \sin x\cos^3 x\,dx=-\int\cos^3 x (-\sin x)\,dx=-\int u^3 \,du$.

Comment: What you have done so far is correct; but to compute the antiderivative this way, you would need to write your whole integrand in terms of $\sin x$. The usual mnemonic is to actually make a change of variable; i.e. define $u = \sin x$ and convert the integrand to one in terms of $u$. @David's suggestion is essentially to do the problem in the same way you suggested, but it requires a little less work.

Comment: I have never heard the word "primitive" used in this way before. Am I the only one who's puzzled by it?? Actually, I'm pretty sure that "primitive" is not a verb (or, it never used to be, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Without substitution:

Suppose you know that $\;\int f(x)dx=F(x)\;$ , and suppose you have a differentiable function $\;g(x)\;$ s.t. $\;f(g(x))\;$ is defined and integrable, then;

$$\int g'(x)\,f(g(x))dx=F(g(x))\;\;\text{(Proof? Apply the Chain Rule to the RHS)}$$

In our case, take

$$\;f(x)=x^3\;\implies \int f(x)dx=\frac14x^4+C\;,\;\;\;g(x)=\cos^3x\;,\;\;\text{so that:}$$

$$\int\sin x\cos^3x\,dx=-\int (-\sin x)\cos^3xdx=-\int(\cos x)'\,\cos^3x\,dx=\frac14\cos^4x+C$$

Comment: You kind of gave a proof of the substitution rule... :)

Comment: Yes, I know @dani_s...yet long years of experience with high school and budding undergraduates have taught me that this way, when seen, is simpler and easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you want your " $u$ " to be $\sin x$, it should be fine too. Then write: $$\sin x \cdot \cos ^3 x  = \sin x \cdot \cos ^2  x\cdot \cos x = \sin x\cdot (1 - \sin ^2x)\cdot \cos x = (\sin x - \sin ^3 x)\cdot \cos x$$. You can proceed to the next step.

Comment: How does $(sinx - sinx^3)*cosx$ suppose to help me to find the primitive more easiliy?

Comment: @Dorians: let u = sinx ==> du = cosxdx, and sinx - sinx^3 = u - u^3.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost immediate. Use $y=\cos(x)$, then $dy = -\sin(x)\,dx$, so

$\displaystyle \int dx\,\sin(x)\cos(x) = -\int dy\,y^3 = -\frac{y^4}{4}+C = -\frac{\cos^4(x)}{4}+C$.